# Initialize Git Repository not present in NetBeans right click menu

Tags: git, netbeans

I am very new to NetBeans 7.0 and have just installed it. I have seen a tuttorial which should allow me to create a Git repository in NetBeans.

But when I go to the Project name and right click the 'Initialize Git repo..' is not present in the listed Version Control Systems.

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netbeans 7 IIRC the git support is in a [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37577/git-versioning-system-support). Check if you've it installed, go to:

> Tools -> Plugins

Search for `git` plugin and install it. From Netbeans 7.2 the git support is integrated in the IDE.